# @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) vs static let shared property

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

Are the following two any different?

1. Using `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc`
2. Calling `PersistentController.shared.container.viewContext` when the `PersistentController.shared` is a `static let` instance, i.e. `static let shared = PersistenceController()`

As I currently understand it, `static let` means one and only instance across the whole application, which is pretty much the same as a singleton.

In my view models I currently pass in `moc` in the contractors to be used later such as (and I'll call `.init(moc)` where `moc` comes from `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext))`

```
init(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
  self.moc = moc
  //the rest are omitted but you get the idea...
}
```

And I was wondering if I can simplify it using the `static let` instance like

```
init() {
   self.moc = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
}
```

Comment: It is is just a static let, how would refresh the views if there are changes?

Comment: I used it to do some on-demand fetching for validation purposes. Currently I do not use moc to refresh views. Views are bonded to and refreshed when a @Published var validationError: String is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should always inject dependencies and never access static/global variables directly.

This removes hidden dependencies and tight coupling between different entities of your codebase and also makes unit testing much easier.

It might seem easier to just access a singleton/static instance directly, however, it will make testability and maintenance of your code much harder.

Comment: Does it mean that if coupling is not a concern, i.e. just a very small app with no intention to write unit tests, then they are exactly the same with no other downsides?

Comment: @Josh Essentially yes.

Answer (score 1):

`@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)` is required by `@FetchRequest`. It also lets us supply a different context loaded with sample data for previews, e.g.

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```